# Sort an array of zeros, ones and twos

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to sort arrays in such a way such that all zeros should come first and then followed by ones and then followed by twos.

> Input: { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1 };
>
> Output: { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 };

Below is my program which doesn't work on my above input:

```
public class SeggregateZeroOneTwos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1 };
        arrangeNumbers(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void arrangeNumbers(int[] arr) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = arr.length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < high) {
            if (arr[i] < 1) {
                swap(arr, i, low);
                low++;
                i++;
            } else if (arr[i] > 1) {
                swap(arr, i, high);
                high--;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i] ^ arr[j];
        arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[j];
    }
}
```

I am getting output as in which you can see, zero is coming in between 1 and 2. What's wrong with the code?

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I'd do a little more research into quick sort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number at high is not checked yet.

```
    while (i <= high) {
```

Comment: Can you explain it little bit so that I can get the idea?

Comment: In the case of `a[i] > 1`, you do `swap(arr, i, high)`.  At that time `arr[high] > 1`.  But after that, you do `high--'.  So `arr[high]` value is not checked yet.

Answer (score 1):

From fast look it seems like you just need to use `i <= high`

```
while (i <= high)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation if possible?

Comment: lets suppose you have array of {1,0}, then 1-st itteration) `i==1`  => `i++` and 2-nd) `i == high` => stop, but you need to loop over 2-nd value.. so you have to use i <= high

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a count sort: single scan the array with three counters. Then just write #0's #1's, #2's back into the array.

Count sort works when:

- Possible domain values are known and cardinality is small
- A small amount of additional storage (equal to the cardinality) is allowed

The count sort is O(n) - faster than any comparison sort.

Comment: Ah I see : yes your algo is O(dn)  where d is the domain size - which is 3.  Eg. If there were 4 domain values you would need an additional comparison.

Comment: Ok got it. So in terms of complexity, they are both same. I am not using any extra storage at all here so might be better than count sort. Right?

Comment: Yes the tradeoff is as you say - some extra storage vs the "d" factor in the o(dn)  . In the case of only 3 domain values yours may be a reasonable choice.